# writing load tests for junit springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, testing, junit

I have written the following junit test.

```
@SpringBootTest
public class abc {

@Autowired
private ActorService actorService;

@Test
@Transactional
public void testCorrectIdHandlingForNewInsertedActors() {
    int elementsInDb = 0;
    for (Actor a : this.actorService.findAll()) {
        elementsInDb++;
    }

    Actor actor = this.actorService.saveAndSetId(new Actor());

    assertEquals(elementsInDb + 1, actor.getId());
}
}
```

Now I want to write some load tests for performance testing but I don't know which tools I can use within my spring application. I am using gradle as my build tool. Any tutorial will be appreciated.

PS: I have already tried zerocode but does not work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some useful features out of the box such as `@RepeatedTest` and `@Timeout` *(see the JUnit 5 annotations reference [here](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-annotations))* which respectively allow you to repeat a specific test method `n` times and set a maximum time limit before a test will fail automatically.

Other than that, for more complete and meaningful load testing you should consider relying on a full-fledged solution such as [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) or [Gatling](https://gatling.io/), rather than unit tests.